# How to build ML model to find the exact words spoken one person in others audio file?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, audio, neural-network, librosa

For example, if I say i have a master audio file which consist of a sentence "apple is my favorite fruit", and some slave audio file which also consist of the same sentence "apple is my favorite fruit" at different timestamp(different for different slave) of audio, I would like to build Machine Learning Model to predict the exact or somehow close timestamp of a of a sentence "apple is my favorite fruit" in an audio file. I have used splitter to extract human voice from the background music or noise and tried two different library librosa and pyaudioanalysis library to extract features.

Comment: What you want to detect is speech. Why not use a speech detection model? Here is an example of a speech model which gives timings of words: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370463/1967571

Comment: I would recommend avoiding the master/slave terminology. More typical for this task would be the audio to query in, and the audio to query with.