# How to silence specific words in an audio file using python?

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, audio-processing, audio-analysis

I want to mute specific words in audio files. I have a list of words that should be muted. I have tried converting the audio file to text using this code but how can I get the time frame of each word so I can mute them?

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import moviepy.editor as mp

r = sr.Recognizer()

audio = sr.AudioFile("Welcome.wav")
print(audio)

with audio as source:
  audio_file = r.record(source)
  print(audio_file)

try:
        # using google speech recognition
        text = r.recognize_google(audio_file)
        print('Converting audio transcripts into text ...')
        print(text)
     
except:
         print('Sorry.. run again...')

# exporting the result 
with open('recognized.txt',mode ='w') as file: 
   file.write("Recognized Speech:") 
   file.write("\n") 
   file.write(text) 
   print("ready!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows [how to get the timestamps of words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370463/1967571). The timestamps can then be used to silence sections containing the words to be muted.

Comment: If I `print(results)` It prints "[]"

Comment: It means no words were found. Check your input audio, and try other files

Comment: I have tried with several audio files and using 'vosk-model-small-en-in-0.4' as well. Still the same issue.

Comment: I got the problem. VOSK was not properly installed. I created a new virtual environment and run it there it worked. Thank you so much.